# lua: http post dynamic

Tags: python, http, lua, http-post

I am trying to consume a web service using Lua programming language. When I run my script, I receive a http error 500. My API is written in Python Flask and this is my Lua script.

```
http = require("socket.http");
ltn12 = require("ltn12");
param_1 = argv[1];
param_2 = argv[2];
path = "http://www.url.com:8080/api/"
body = [[ {"number_id":"b8ce37fb-2061-4aea-975b-57a8e2d355ce","caller_number":param_1,"called_number":param_2} ]]
response_body = { }
res, code, response_headers, status = http.request
{
    url = path,
    method = "POST",
    headers =
    {
          ["X-Access-Key"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
          ["Content-Length"] = body:len()
    },
    source = ltn12.source.string(body),
}
```

I have received the following python traceback:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 70 (char 69)(185.22                                                                                                             2.62.80)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/TVS/tokens-via-sva/app/controllers/api/codes.py", line 31, in crea                                                                                                             te_code
    data = json.loads(request.data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 70 (char 69)
```

what could the origin of the problem?

Comment: Probably, request returned invalid JSON, and python crashed.  Could you show `request.data` before invocation of `json.loads`?

Comment: i got this `b' {"number_id":"b8ce37fb-2061-4aea-975b-57a8e2d355ce","caller_number":caller_id_number,"called_number":caller_destination} '`

Comment: What is `caller_id_number`? Have you replaced actual data with this string when posting it here?  Or does the JSON exactly match the string you have given?

Comment: Actually I made a mistake, the result I got in the backend is `{"number_id":"b8ce37fb-2061-4aea-975b-57a8e2d355ce","caller_number":param_1,"called_number":param_2} '`

Comment: You should insert real data in the string `body = [[ .... ]]` instead of variable name.  For example, replace `:param_1,` with `:"]]..param_1..[[",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua does not support the very common format to make a http body. 
The specific format in lua is to insert real data in the string body = [[ .... ]] instead of variable name.
in this case:

```
body = [[ {"number_id":"b8ce37fb-2061-4aea-975b-57a8e2d355ce","caller_number":"]]..param_1..[[","called_number":"]]..param_2..[["} ]];
```